# dotnet docker container show restore error

Tags: .net, docker

[image]

WebApi/Docekrfile:

```
# Copy everything
COPY . ./
# Restore as distinct layers
RUN dotnet restore
# Build and publish a release
RUN dotnet publish -c Release -o out

# Build runtime image
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:6.0
WORKDIR /App
COPY --from=build-env /App/out .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "WebApi.dll"]
```

docker-compose -f services.yml -f proxy.yml up

```
ERROR [testpoc-webapi build-env 4/5] RUN dotnet restore
```

and also Admin and Portal

Portal/Dockerfile:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0 AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["Portal/Portal.csproj", "Portal"]
RUN dotnet restore "Portal/Portal.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/Portal"
RUN dotnet build "Portal.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "Portal.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish

FROM nginx:alpine AS final
WORKDIR /usr/share/nginx/html
COPY --from=publish /app/publish/wwwroot .
COPY ["Portal/nginx.conf", "/etc/nginx/nginx.conf"]
```

running on window docker. and the TESTPOC in D://Code/TESTPOC

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the problem for your docker image on the last code snippet shows"

```
...
COPY ["Portal/Portal.csproj", "Portal"]
RUN dotnet restore "Portal/Portal.csproj"
COPY . .
...
```

Here's the chain of events:

1. The first statement copies only the Portal/Portal.csproj to the "/src/Portal" directory.
2. `dotnet restore` on the Portal/Portal.csproj, but there's nothing else in that directory except that project file.
3. Copy everything to the /src directory.

I believe you're going to want this instead:

```
...
COPY "Portal/" "Portal"
RUN dotnet restore "Portal/Portal.csproj"
...
```

This should copy everything from the project "Portal" to the "/src/Portal" directory ready for restoring.

Comment: webapi dockerfile not work also. and I fixed it as you say. but show
```
ERROR [testpoc-portal build 3/7] COPY Portal/, Portal
```

Comment: @otterotter Can you confirm that a `dotnet restore` in each of your project directories works and restores the packages without error?